# Showing Unique Key instead of Foreign Key TypeOrm - MySql

Tags: mysql, node.js, foreign-keys, typeorm, unique-key

Might be this is a silly mistake but I need to understand this one. I am just creating a simple example of one to one relation with MySql DB (with TypeOrm), I was gone through the same document provided on typeorm.io.

https://typeorm.io/#/one-to-one-relations

When I am creating One To One relation with User and Profile entities it's showing, profile Id as Unique key instead of foreign key on User Table. Can you please make me clear here, just go through docs for one to one relationship.

Added Entities Code :

User.ts

```
import {Entity,PrimaryGeneratedColumn,Column,OneToOne ,JoinColumn} from "typeorm";
import { Profile } from "./Profile";

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToOne(() => Profile)
  @JoinColumn()
  profile: Profile;
}
```

Profile.ts

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class Profile {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  gender: string;

  @Column()
  photo: string;
}
```

User table description, here I highlighted ****UNI******, I Think here needs to show FOREIGN KEY

```
mysql> desc user;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)    | NO | PRI   | NULL | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(255) | NO  |  NULL | |
| profileId | int(11) |  YES | ****UNI***** | NULL |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Thanks.

Comment: profileId shouldn't be PRI or primary key in users table, instead, it should be a unique foreign key (since it is a one-to-one relation) so I don't think there is anything wrong here.

Comment: profileId isn't meant to be a primary key, the primary key in the user table is "id". In the documentation that you linked profileId is shown as ForeignKey in user's table which I think is the case here too, so nothing to worry.

Comment: @Osama can you please read the updated question, it's my mistake I updated .

Comment: A foreign key in a one-to-one relationship is supposed to be unique so I guess it is not a problem if table description is showing UNI instead of FK. Try making a many to many relation and then I think it will show FK.